# What does `@` mean when not appending any variable name?

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Playing around with MariaDB I accidentally found out that it's possible to use `@` without giving a variable name. I executed following statement:

```sql
SELECT @ INTO @;
```

I would have expected a syntax error since the variable name was omitted, but instead it executes just fine. Now I'm wondering what is happening.

How does MariaDB interpret the `@` symbol in this case? What does this `SELECT` actually do? Or is it just completely ignored without any further operation?

Comment: `@` is apparently an acceptable variable name. try `set @ = 'foo'; select @;`

Comment: It works in MySQL as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although neither the [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/user-variables.html) nor [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/user-defined-variables/) documentation specifically mentions it, apparently user-defined variable are allowed to have an empty name. `@` is the same as `@''`, and it's treated just like any other variable.

So

```
SELECT @ INTO @;
```

is like

```
SELECT @myvar INTO @myvar;
```

It's a useless statement, since it's just assigning a variable to itself, equivalent to

```
SET @ = @;
```